# Would a better graphics card or more cores make Mathematica faster?

Tags: performance, wolfram-mathematica, hardware

In general, can Mathematica automatically (i.e. without writing code specifically for this) exploit GPU hardware and/or parallelize built-in operations across multiple cores?

For example, for drawing a single very CPU-intensive plot or solving a very CPU-intensive equation, would upgrading the graphics hardware result in speed-up? Would upgrading to a CPU with more cores speed things up? (I realize that more cores mean I could solve more equations in parallel but I'm curious about the single-equation case)

Just trying to get a handle on how Mathematica exploits hardware.

Comment: I would imagine it depends upon the operation and if it utilizes the GPU, and in what way. I would daresay that *most* compound operations do not utilize the GPU, as GPU programming is significantly different from CPU programming. For instance, a FFT fits well into a GPU model, but a set of equations that can't be dealt with via linear algebra is likely an entirely different story.

Comment: I guess I'm asking if built-in Mathematica functions use the GPU...

Comment: You stated/implied that it does .. missing a word? :) The Mathematica formums/brochure would be the places to find that out: definitely not here, unless the question was about writing such operations.

Comment: my short experience with doing basic simulations in M, is that the computation in M is VERY fast, but what seems to me to slow things, is the rendering of plots and graphics. So anything you can do to optimize this part (smarter way of making plots/graphics, using options such as `PerformanceGoal->"Speed"` and `MaxPlotPoints` and many other things like this would help. So I would imagine a faster graphics card, would help. As for other aspects, M can utilize GPU's with CUDA. I do not use this part of it.

Comment: @Nasser, much the same for me. Rendering Histograms and DateListPlots is often the rate determining step -- even with `PerformanceGoal->"Speed"`. DateListPlot is slow because date and time functions in Mma are very slow. I'd like to see a 50 times speed improvement to make them competitive with e.g. VBA.

Comment: The close votes on this question are more evidence of why we need a [Mathematica-specific StackExchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica).

Comment: @Verbeia - I respect your optimism but don't set your expectations too high. Technical experts in administrative ( power ) roles can become bossy know-it-alls and thus alienate others.

Comment: @ndroock1 I think that conversation belongs in chat

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wouldn't say Mathematica does automatically GPU or Paralell-CPU computing, at least in general.  Since you need do something with paralell kernels, then  you should initialize more kernels and/or upload CUDALink or OpenCLLink and use specific Mathematica functionality to exploit the potential of CPU and/or GPU.

For example, I haven't got very powerful graphics card (NVIDIA GeForce 9400 GT) but we can test  how CUDALink works.  First I have to upload `CUDALink` :

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]
```

I am going to test multiplication of large matrices. I choose a random matrix `5000 x 5000` of real numbers in range `(-1,1)` :

`M = RandomReal[{-1,1}, {5000, 5000}];`

Now we can check the computing times without GPU support

```
  In[4]:= AbsoluteTiming[ Dot[M,M]; ]

  Out[4]= {26.3780000, Null}
```

and with GPU support

```
In[5]:= AbsoluteTiming[ CUDADot[M, M]; ]

Out[5]= {6.6090000, Null}
```

In this case we obtained a performance speed-up roughly of factor 4, by using CUDADot instead of Dot.

**Edit**

To add an example of parallel CPU acceleration (on a dual-core machine) I choose all prime numbers in range `[2^300, 2^300 +10^6]`.
 First without parallelizing :

```
In[139]:= AbsoluteTiming[ Select[ Range[ 2^300, 2^300 + 10^6], PrimeQ ]; ]

Out[139]= {121.0860000, Null}
```

while using `Parallelize[expr]`, which evaluates expr using automatic parallelization

```
In[141]:= AbsoluteTiming[ Parallelize[ Select[ Range[ 2^300, 2^300 + 10^6], PrimeQ ] ]; ]

Out[141]= {63.8650000, Null}
```

As one could expect we've got almost two times faster evaluation.

Comment: Hi Artes, I have a related question. I am getting a new laptop mainly to use with Mathematica. Are you saying that I should focus on CPU only and not put much emphasis on the GPU then?

Comment: @Y2H It's a bit too general problem,  basically you can get a lot from your GPU nevertheless I'd say it's of secondary importance,  first mind the CPU and RAM, even more important  will be style of programming in `Mathematica`.

Answer (score 8):

Generally no, a faster GPU will not accelerate normal *Mathematica* computations.

You must be using Cuda/OpenCL supported functions to use the GPU.  You can get an overview of the options and some samples of their use here:  [CUDA and OpenCL Support](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/cuda-and-opencl-support/).

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment much on how Mathematica uses the GPU (as I never had the chance to try), but I don't believe it does it by default ([i.e without you writing code specifically to exploit the GPU](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CUDALink/guide/CUDALink.html))

Adding more cores will help if you explicitly parallelize your calculations ([see `Parallelize` and related functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ParallelComputing.html)).

If you don't parallelize explicitly, I believe there are still certain numerical calculations that take advantage of multiple cores.  I'm not sure which one, but I do know that some linear algebra related functions (`LinearSolve`, `Det`, etc.) use multiple cores by default.

Comment: I know some of the image processing operations will also use multiple cores by default.

Comment: Solving an eigensystem (dense or sparse) also uses many cores automatically

Comment: @acl I tried `Eigenvalues` on a dual core CPU, but it only used one core.  Maybe `Eigensystem` does but `Eigenvalues` doesn't (that'd be unusual)?  I can't test right now.

Comment: It definitely does use 2 or 4 cores for finding the first 100 eigenvectors of a sparse system that I just tried. This may depend on the machine, as it probably just uses LAPACK (I assume mma includes its own libraries though).

Comment: It should be added that the number of parallel processes you can run depends on your license. On a standard license, Parallelize will distribute the computation, if possible, between 4 kernels. You can of course have a license that allows more or use gridMathematica.

Comment: So, I just tried `With[{upN = 10000, sites = 2000}, sp = SparseArray[Thread[RandomInteger[{1, sites}, {upN, 2}] -> RandomReal[{0, 1}, upN]], {sites, sites}]]; {evals, evecs} = Eigensystem[sp, -500];` (which creates a sparse array and then obtains the eigenvalues and eigenvectors) and it uses both cores of my macbook. I also ran it on one of my office machines via ssh and it uses all 4 cores there (linux).

Comment: @Searke The license limits the number of parallel kernels you may start; however, what I am describing is a single mathkernel taking 200% (or 400%). I am not sure if that is limited by licensing or not, and have no way of checking.

Comment: @Searke You can check that using `$MaxLicenseSubprocesses`.  Like acl, I don't believe this limitation applies to multicore-aware numerical computations like `LinearSolve`.